# Get Angular to use initial input data while sending form even if user entered nothing inside input box

Tags: html, angular, forms, input

I have the following input form component

```
<input class="form-control" #FirstName="ngModel" name="FirstName" [(ngModel)]="formModel.FirstName" value="{{userProfile?.firstName}}">
```

Where I render some initial data while rendering page.

My goal is to send this initial data when submiting this form even if nothing was entered inside the form from user. How can I achive it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular use case I would suggest you to use reactive forms.As you can use the formControl and add your default value as a part of the formControl.

```
formItem = new FormControl('default Value');
onSubmit(){
data = this.formItem.value;
}
```

If we are using the template driven form 
The we can use NgSubmit directive and add the resective logic to pick data from the template reference that you have provided.

**Template driven forms:**
https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit

**Reactive forms**
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-generating-and-importing-a-new-form-control

Comment: If I enter some default values manually everything works fine reactive way. 
Problem is that I call some method which gets data the same moment this page is rendered. Is there a way to get data first and then declare formModel ???

Comment: Yes so in your onInit lifecycle what you can is wait for the response based on which a flag is placed which will do a ngIf for your form so that form is not rendered.
the next part is you can set the control value by looping on the response and getting the value out of the object and setting it as the default value when you create your formControl or your formModel.
Ensure that your template is rendered after the response is bound to your formModel object or added as a default value while using the fomrControl.